# Are the breadcrumbs correct here?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am wondering if the breadcrumbs I put there are correct. As far as I know breadcrumbs are supposed to show the longest path a user can go to a particular place. So here it is.

However I'm not sure it's correct considering my navigation. I have a sidebar with a few categories, one of which is "Joined games" which consists of particular games. Each game page has a few tabs (shown here as well), one of which is "Blog", where a user can scroll through a lot of posts and choose specific one and enter its own page - and this is the page that I attached. So we're on the particular blog post's page.

This is the level that I no longer have any other indication of (neither in the sidebar nor in the tabs at the top), hence the breadcrumbs, which I do not have yet in any other place in the project.

Are they displayed correctly? Or is there something I should change due to the way my navigation works?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your breadcrumb navigation is correct.

But user may confuse with the place of heading and tabs (Game title 1, tabs)
with in the Joined games category we have "Game title 1" with in this we have 5 tabs.

so first Game title 1 Heading should come then tabs will show.

Please check the bolow updated screenshot Game title 1 heading show on top and tabs are showing below "Game title 1"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Breadcrumb can be used in case there is multi level connection between screens so that it is easier for users to know where they are. In this case the navigation is straight forward and hence not recommended.